# How to get YouTube Videos to show up & play in Android Apps?

Tags: android, youtube

Our Android app loads RSS feeds for news and blog sites and displays the stories in a webview.

Whenever a story has a YouTube video, the video doesn't show up and it doesn't play (the object is there, but it's just whitespace & nothing happens when you tap it)

Surely, since Google owns both Android and YouTube there's simple way to allow YouTube videos to play in a webview within Android Apps?? (They work great in our iPhone app).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

you can't play them in the webview because android doesn't have flash (well, that isn't entirely true now, but not all devices even support the android version of flash). To play them, the link should launch the youtube player that is on "google powered" devices.

It works on the iOS because the browser "converts" the video to a playable format. android browser does not do that.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was adding three lines to the meta tag at the top of your HTML. These three lines should allow you to embed Youtube videos to your mobile app.

```
https://*.youtube.com 
https://*.youtubeusercontent.com 
https://*.youtubeapis.com
```

Your full tag should look like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://*.gstatic.com https://*.youtube.com https://*.youtubeusercontent.com https://*.youtubeapis.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

I tried other methods inside the AndroidManifest.xml and config.xml but those did not work for me. I hope this helps - Adam